# Java 7 or 8 is required to Run .Jar (Linux)

Tags: linux, java-7, java-8

This is a newly installed centos 6.2 x86_64 I have downloaded java 8u5 rpm for linux to run a .jar file, but I am unable to. I have removed java through terminal through the command "rpm -e jar-1.8.0_05", and have attempted to reinstall it, though I still get the same error. I have also attempted to install java 7u60, but I still get the same error.

I am now on java 8u5, trying to find a fix for this.

Image:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/f0kzk.png

Comment: How are you running the jar file?

Comment: @dfb I open it via 2x click. I've also tried the command "java -jar filename.jar", but I still get the same error.

Comment: Try `rpm -ql <pkgname>` on the RPM for 1.7 or 1.8 to find the the location of that JRE and try again. Also, try running `java --version` to see which one you're currently using

Comment: @dfb I tried rpm -q jre, and it says I'm using "jre-1.8.0_05-fcs.i586". Also tried the rpm -ql <pkgname>, but the .jar file still gives the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Try running

```
cd <path to jar file>
/user/java/jre1.8.0_05/bin/java -jar <jarname>
```

Comment: is there anything I can do?